# jQuery selector, cant pass through

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have

```
echo '<div><span>'.$wiersz['data'].'<i> added by: '.$wiersz['username'].'</i></span><span>Rate: </span><i **FROM HERE**>'.$wiersz['likes'].'</i><i>'.$wiersz['unlikes'].'</i></div>';

echo '<div><span>'.$wiersz['data'].'<i> added by: '.$wiersz['username'].'</i></span><span>Rate: <i>Thank you</i></span><i **OVERHERE**>'.$wiersz['likes'].'</i> <i>'.$wiersz['unlikes'].'</i></div>';
```

How Can I go FROM (FROM HERE) to the (OVER HERE) by selectors in jQuery?
I'm hiding first div and showing second div. I need to increase innerText of OVERHERE but I dont know how to go there by selectors.

I did:

```
$(this).parent().next()
```

this lead me to second div but still cant go into OVERHERE in second div.

Comment: That one line of jQuery is totally meaningless all by itself. We have no idea what you are looking for, what `this` is, or how this code gets run

Comment: Show us the *actual HTML code*!.  There is absolutely no reason to show us the PHP code that generates it.

Comment: Come on. There is next to no PHP here

Comment: Actual html is first line. This html is given dynamically.

Comment: $(this).closest("div").find("i").eq(2).innerHTML = parseInt(this.innerHTML) + 1;

This dont change innertext in OVERHERE selector :c

Comment: @xqz No, the actual HTML is not shown. The PHP that *generates the HTML* is what you are showing us. Run the PHP code and copy/paste the *actual HTML* into your question.

Comment: Totally agree...shouldn't have to read html as strings that negate syntax highlighting with proper code

Comment: Well, guy below give ma a good answer and didnt need html code. Possible? Possible. :D

Comment: @xqz That is not the point. Your question is about jQuery. It has absolutely **nothing** to do with PHP. Since the PHP code generates the HTML, there is no reason for you to not show us the actual HTML code.

Comment: HAD you posted HTML I would have realised quicker that the container div was the parent of the <i> and would have posted a parent() sooner. Now I wasted my time on formatting for no reason at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
$(this).parent().next().children()[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is how the rendered HTML looks like

```
<div>
  <span>data<i> added by: username</i></span>
  <span>Rate: </span>
  <i onclick="$(this).closest('div').next().find('i').eq(2).text(parseInt($(this).text(),10))">25 Likes</i>
  <i>unlikes</i>
</div>
<div>
  <span>data<i> added by: username</i></span>
  <span>Rate: <i>Thank you</i></span><i>Will be overwritten </i> <i>unlikes</i>
</div>
```

Or `$(this).parent().next()` instead. However closest is safer in case you wrap your `<i>` in something